# How to track which external link users who registered on my site came from

Tags: 6, nodes, google-analytics

Google Analytics shows how many and from which links people have visited to my site as I have installed the [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module. How can I know from which link the individual registered users came from?  For example, I would like to know something like:

> The user (uid:30) came from  http://example.com
>   The user (uid:31) came from  http://somesite.com

Or do I have to ask users directly by making a kind of "Where did you know about us" profile field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe StatCounter allows for this
http://statcounter.com/
http://drupal.org/project/statcounter

I believe what your asking for is against GA's TOS http://drupal.org/node/318974

Comment: OK so google analytic practically can track individual users (by custom variables of uid or something as afar as I understand ) but it's not allowed to do so by thier TOS.On the other hand statcounter doesn't have this kind of restriction. Am I correct?

Comment: From my understanding that is correct